# Is it possible to display two ImageViews within a PageViewer?

Tags: android, imageview, android-viewpager

I have a working ViewPager app which renders an ImageView.  This ImageView fills the screen in portrait mode but when the user orientates their device to landscape I wish to display the current ImageView on the left and the next ImageView in the sequene on the right.

Currently in landscape the ImageView is simply displayed in the centre of the screen.

I know that I have to define a res/layout-land version of the PageViewer layout, but more than that I don't know.

Is this possible?

Thanks,

Mark.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible to display more than 1 view on a viewpager (doesn't matter if youre using horizontal or vertical orientation). What you could try is creating 2 viewpagers, but this may become confusing (updating the positions on both viewpagers.. as I assume you want to update the images like flipping through a book). Viewpagers are quite limiting in that sense.

You can try using a `ViewFlipper`, instead, which allows more flexibility.

Comment: Aimango, thanks.  I was starting to come to that conclusion myself.